# how to create alert box for popup button and also for submit button?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have done alert for submit button and its working. but for the same page i have two popup buttons for them also i have to add alert but it wont work for me. Please help in this: I have my alert code which work for only submit button:

```js
(function() {
  var proxied = window.alert;
  window.alert = function() {
    $("#myModal .modal-body").text(arguments[0]);
    $("#myModal").modal('show');
  };
  var myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 100000000000000000000);
})();
alert('SUCCESS');

function myTimer() {
  window.location.assign('job_schedule');;
}

function redirectfun() {
  window.location.assign('job_schedule');  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/js/bootstrap.js">
  </script>
  <meta charset=utf-8 />
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria- labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
      <h3 id="myModalLabel">Alert</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="redirectfun()" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Can you revisit your question ? It is not clear what you are asking..

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I really understand your question, but you can try this:

```
function your_function_name(){
    if (!confirm("Please Confirm - Yes or No?")) return;
    //following your codes ...
}
```